# Why is my webpage saying [object HTMLParagraphElement]?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, getelementbyid

when I try to use javascript to write to an id in html, I get this: [object HTMLParagraphElement]
I am using innerhtml but it still doesn't work. I looked at different answers but none seemed to help

here is my code:

```js
var cashs = 0;
```

```html
<p id="cashs"></p>
<script>document.getElementById('cashs').innerHTML = cashs;</script>
```

Comment: What is cashs?  Is it supposed to be string? If so, you missed quotations.

Comment: cashs is the name of the Id and also a variable

Comment: @joeisme1 please post whole code.

Comment: I figured it out. I was just being dumb. I just didnt put the variales in the js

Answer (score 1):

Because any element in the document that contains `id' is defined in the code as a variable that indicates its element by default

```
<p id="a"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
a.innerHTML="Hello";
</script>
```

**Results:**

`<p id="a">Hello</p>`